# "Insistently believing that this is a photo of Neil Armstrong in the face of everyone else's..." Can one really insistently believe something?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-meaning

The sub-context is that there's an iconic photo of Apollo astronaut Buzz Aldrin on the Moon taken by a large format Hasselblad camera and in Aldrin's gold reflective visor one can see the photographer Neil Armstrong in their space suit. Though the image is pretty small one can recognize the details of the suit, the camera being held, and through a *process of elimination* can determine which of the two astronauts it is.

Please let us not debate under this question post itself if the photo can or can not be characterized as a photo of (among other things) a photo of Neil Armstrong. Passions tend to run high when I suggest that it *could be* characterized that way.

Here I'd like to consider if a phrase that turned up in comments reflects a proper usage of the two adjacent words.

> **Insistently believing** that this is a photo of Neil Armstrong in the face of everyone else's description of the photo as one of Buzz Aldrin that has a small reflection of Neil Armstrong, is the classic definition of dogma.

**Question:** In this sentence should "Insistently believing that..." be taken as an assertion that I am "insisting" upon something simply by "believing" it? To me there seems to be some fundamental dissonance, that the mere act of belief and absence of a "you're right, I'm wrong" is the same as insisting on something, either that the existence of my opinion is an act imposed on or statement made to others, or my failure to yield is.

Can we use these words in this way and be faithful to the range of definitions and usages they are understood to span?

---

- Cambridge.org: [insist](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/insist): "to say firmly or demand forcefully, especially when others disagree with or oppose what you say"
- [Oxford Languages](https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en/) via google: insist: "demand something forcefully, not accepting refusal."
- Cambridge.org: [believe](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/believe): "to think that something is true, correct, or real"
- [Oxford Languages](https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en/) via google: believe: "1. accept that (something) is true, especially without proof. 2. hold (something) as an opinion; think.

---

For further context and background relating to the phrase's genesis:

- Space SE: [Lot 345 of Christie's “Voyage To Another World” auction supposedly has the only photo of Armstrong on the Moon, but isn't this one also?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48462/12102)
- Skeptics SE: [Is there only one photograph of Neil Armstrong on the Moon?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/49848/57844)

Comment: I'm not sure if I've included the appropriate tags; the question asks about the use of "insistent" in describing a "belief" but I don't know if that's considered a phrase.

Comment: Google Books instances: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=insistently+believe%2C+stubbornly+believe+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinsistently%20believe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstubbornly%20believe%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @user121863 apparently some stubbornly believe that "insistently believe" is not necessarily incorrect.

Comment: @uhoh I agree that although one phrase is more common than the other, the two phrases are **not** synonymous, and therefore comparison is not a particularly good guide: Human nature is such that it is more common to *stubbornly* believe something than it is to *insistently* believe something. If you "*insistently*" believe something, then you continually demand that you are correct: with *stubbornly* you may make no comment at all

Comment: @Greybeard **Nobody said that they were synonymous**. I do not see them as synonymous and I do not think that was the point of the previous comment either. Instead, I see it as a *comparable phrase* for the purposes of looking at the comparison in ngram and writing a short SE comment, and for the purposes of suggesting a better phrase that the the comment author might have chosen to convey their sentiment in a less grammatically stressful way.

Comment: A large part of the body of this question is taken up by a lengthy presentation of an example that only distracts the reader from the actual question.

Comment: The definitions of 'insistently' I've looked up (I'm not sure why 'insist' has been looked up rather than the adverb) have **action**, whether volitional- ('He knocked insistently on the door') or personificational- ('The bell rang insistently') agentive-subject, verbs. Not mental process verbs.

Comment: @jsw29 I try to avoid that happening with the eye-catching **Question:** heading, though that's not foolproof. In this particular case I feel that more than an average amount of context is important and necessary because while seemingly awkward or dissonant, it might turn out that  "Insistently believing..." works in certain cases, and this might be one of them. I don't think so, but I thought I would err on the side of caution.

Comment: @uhoh *Nobody said that they were synonymous ...I see it as a comparable phrase  for [...] suggesting a better phrase that the [...] author might have chosen to convey their sentiment* - well, if it isn't a synonym, then that is not what the author meant to convey. There is nothing wrong with "insistently believing" in the meaning of "insistently expressing and or defending one's belief."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, saying that somebody 'insistently believes' something is indeed odd. What makes it odd is that insisting on something normally proceeds from a conscious choice, while believing, as usually understood, doesn't. (One may choose whether to consider evidence for something, but after one has finished examining and weighing the evidence, it either leads one to believe it, or it doesn't; there is no room for any insisting to take place.) Moreover, insisting is something that one normally does when interacting with others, while believing takes place, so to speak, in one's own head.

The people who might be tempted to say that somebody 'insistently believes' something, either want to say that he focuses a great deal of conscious attention on that belief, or that he insistently defends that belief in interaction with others.

Comment: This is on the right lines but it doesn't seem the exact distinction. You can insist on something on the basis of something irrational (a feeling or even a belief) as well as from a conscious choice, but you can't insistently believe. The idea that insistence is done to others while belief is in one's head is closer to the truth: insistence involves repeated action, commonly directed towards others, while belief is more of a state of being in which ideas exist without moving or being projected. Insistence need not be conscious or deliberate, but it must be manifested in repeated action.

Comment: Of course, people can (and often do) insist on something irrationally; saying that a choice is conscious does not imply that it is rational.